# gcc cannot find ansinist.h even though it is there in /usr/incude/ansinist

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am trying to make a program provided by NIST. I do not have much experience in such tasks.

I am getting the following error.

```
util.c:19:22: fatal error: ansinist.h: No such file or directory 
#include <ansinist.h>
```

`ansinist` is available in the current directory, project base directory and I have also copied it to `/usr/include/aninist` but still getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the header file in `/usr/include/aninist`, you need to call it like,

```
#include <aninist/ansinist.h>
```

Or you can put the header file is in your current directory and call like,

```
#include "./ansinist.h"
```

or you could use,

```
#include "/path/to/ansinist.h"
```